# Delphi Indy POST file without "fieldname" in TIdMultiPartFormDataStream

Tags: file, delphi, post, indy

Using Delphi 10.1.
Need to send image to this site: www.flagma.ru

At sniffer requests:

```
URL:https://flagma.ru/messageuploadphoto.php?qqfile=111.jpg
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Referer: https://flagma.ru/my/1538481/podat-obyavlenie.html
X-File-Name:111.jpg
X-Mime-Type: image/jpeg
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

My Delphi trying:

```
http.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
  http.Request.Accept := '*/*';
  http.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7';
  http.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
  http.Request.Referer := 'https://flagma.ru/my/1538481/podat-obyavlenie.html';

  fnShort := ExtractFileName(fn); // fn - full image file
  url := 'https://flagma.ru/messageuploadphoto.php?qqfile=' + fnShort;
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Mime-Type', 'image/jpeg');
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-File-Name', fnShort);
  http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

  (* it is wrong way
  a := TStringStream.Create(tempa);
  formData := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  formData.Clear; 
  formData.AddFile('qqfile', fn, GetMIMETypeFromFile(fn));

  try
    http.Post(url, formData, a);
  except
    on E: EIdException do
    begin
      response := '';
    end;
  end;
  formData.Free;
  response := utf8Decode(a.DataString);
 *)
```

Solution is just:  **response := http.Post(url, fn);**

And getting error: Imagу has small width and height. But in browser same file  is ok.

Comment: You make a multipart form data where the file is just one of the fields, but in mimetype you specifically set `image/jpeg`. That collides. Either send just an image, and load it straight into the request body, or create multipart form data and let the request headers actually specify that it's multipart form data. Which one you need I don't know. That depends on the process that receives the request.

Comment: Thanks! Decision is just:  response := http.Post(url, fn);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is expecting the file to be posted as-is in the `POST` body. As such, you need to use the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` that takes a plain `TStream`, such as a `TFileStream`, instead of using the overload that takes a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`:

```pascal
http.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
http.Request.Accept := '*/*';
http.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7';
//http.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
http.Request.Referer := 'https://flagma.ru/my/1538481/podat-obyavlenie.html';

fnShort := ExtractFileName(fn); // fn - full image file
url := 'https://flagma.ru/messageuploadphoto.php?qqfile=' + fnShort;
http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Mime-Type'] := GetMIMETypeFromFile(fn);
http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-File-Name'] := fnShort;
http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Requested-With'] := 'XMLHttpRequest';

fs := TFileStream.Create(fn, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
try
  try
    response := http.Post(url, fs);
  except
    response := '';
  end;
finally
  fs.Free;
end;

{ alternatively: you can pass the full file path to Post()...
try
  response := http.Post(url, fn);
except
  response := '';
end;}
```